# How to transform a pandas dataframe into a heatmap compatible dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, heatmap

I have a pandas dataframe which looks something like this:

```
  x_specie   y_species         r_value        irrelevant 
0    name1    name2    0.46042854769889    1.08625581318480
1    name3    name4    0.08520026289205    0.31828185948920
2    name5    name6    0.59751876928376    0.03611201620948
3    name7    name8    0.21827455728522    1.28464913995526
4    name9    name10    0.03241820474363    0.69957843027741
```

Something similar can be generated with:

```
Index= ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
Cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df = DataFrame(abs(np.random.randn(5, 4)), index=Index, columns=Cols)
```

Essentially I want to make a heat map of the r_value column using matplotlibs `ax.pcolor()` but I need to first get this data into an appropriate format which I believe is something like this:

```
     name2     name4     name6    name8    name10
name1 r_value1 ...       ...               ...
name3 ...      ...
name5                    ...
name7                             ...
name9 ...                                  ...
```

with the r_values populating the table in the right places (note that though the dummy data above doesn't cover all the potential combinations my actual data does).

What is the easiest way to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry are you after `df.pivot(index='x_specie', columns = 'y_species', values='r_value')`?

Comment: exactly what I'm after. Seems like pandas have thought of everything...Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [pivot_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to get all the combos of x and y species (filling NaNs with 0).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

pivoted_table = df.pivot(index='x_specie', columns='y_species', values='r_value')
pivoted_table.fillna(0, inplace=True)
plt.pcolor(pivoted_table.values, cmap=plt.cm.Reds)
plt.show()
```